# Are Facebook programming questions now "off topic"?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, off-topic, facebook

With the advent of [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/), are Facebook-related programming questions that are on the standard Stack Overflow site now "off topic"? Am I justified in flagging them as off topic?

If they aren't off topic, how will we discourage users from posting the questions to the main site?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You've greatly misunderstood what facebook.stackoverflow.com is.  **It is not a separate site.  All it is is a filter**.  Anything that appears on facebook.stackoverflow.com exists on stackoverflow.com proper.  Take any question you see on facebook.stackoverflow.com and remove facebook from the url.  You'll see the exact same question on SO proper.

A question entered on facebook.stackoverflow.com is visible to anyone on stackoverflow.com, not just the subsite.

So yes, if it is a valid programming question then it is perfectly fine on stackoverflow.com and flagging these as off-topic is inappropriate.

Comment: Gotcha! I suspected that the sites were interrelated but since the URLs for questions on the fb.so site seemed be distinct (had `facebook.` in the URL), I thought they were separate. Thanks!

Comment: OH, look!  Its the "I Hate facebook.SO" robot!:  http://static1.robohash.com/I%20Hate%20facebook.SO